# js animate() method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am making a animated wheel for my project and it is supposed to work like this:
the user clicks the next button and with an animation the wheel turns 90 degrees and an item  will appear, I must say that each of these 4 items are placed on the wheel and no js code is applied on them, the code's job is jusr to turn the wheel in the direction that the user clicks on. The code works fine on a single direction, however when you click on the opposingg direction there's a jump, and with the second click on the same direction the animation plays just as expected.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="drinks-wheel-section">
    <div class="drinks-wheel">
        <div class="drinks-wrapper wrapper1">
            <div class="drink-picture --1"></div>
            <div class="drink-picture --2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="drinks-wrapper wrapper2">
            <div class="drink-picture --3"></div>
            <div class="drink-picture --4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="name-and-change">
        <span class="previous">< </span>
        <p class="drink-name"></p>
        <span class="next">></span>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="s.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.drinks-wheel-section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    position: relative;
}

.drinks-wheel{
    width: 30rem;
    height: 30rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.drink-picture{
    width: 7rem;
    height: 7rem;
}
.--1{
    background-color: aqua;
}

.--2{
    background-color: darkblue;
}

.--3{
    background-color: black;
}

.--4{
    background-color: brown;
}

.drinks-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 7rem;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 1rem;
}


.wrapper1{
    top: 37%;
    left: 0%;
}

.wrapper2{
    rotate: 90deg;
    top: 38%;
    left: 0%;
}

.name-and-change{
    width: 15%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
}

.next,.previous{
    font-size: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
const $ = document
const previousBtn = $.querySelector(".previous")
const nextBtn = $.querySelector(".next")
const CurrentDrinkName = $.querySelector(".drink-name")
const drinksWheel = $.querySelector(".drinks-wheel")

let rotateAmountFrom = 0
let rotateAmountTo = 0

function showNextOrPreviousDrink (e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains("previous")) {
        rotateAmountFrom = rotateAmountTo
        rotateAmountTo = rotateAmountTo + 90
        let animationRotate = [
            {rotate: rotateAmountFrom + "deg"},
            {rotate: rotateAmountTo + "deg"},
        ]
        drinksWheel.animate(animationRotate,{fill: "forwards",duration:800,})
    
    } else {
        rotateAmountFrom = rotateAmountTo
        rotateAmountTo = rotateAmountTo + 90    
        let animationRotate = [
            {rotate: "-" + rotateAmountFrom + "deg"},
            {rotate: "-" + rotateAmountTo + "deg"},
        ]
        drinksWheel.animate(animationRotate,{fill: "forwards",duration:800,})

    }
    console.log(rotateAmountFrom,rotateAmountTo,)
}
nextBtn.addEventListener("click",showNextOrPreviousDrink)
previousBtn.addEventListener("click",showNextOrPreviousDrink)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use in CSS `transition: rotate 0.8s;` and in JavaScript simply account the degrees of change to a `deg` variable, and use `` elWheel.style.rotate = `${deg}deg`; ``

Example:

```js
const el = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelector(sel);

const elPrev = el(".prev");
const elNext = el(".next");
const elWheel = el(".drinks-wheel");

let deg = 0

const rotate = (degChange) => {
  deg += degChange
  elWheel.style.rotate = `${deg}deg`;
};

elNext.addEventListener("click", () => rotate(90));
elPrev.addEventListener("click", () => rotate(-90));
```

```css
.drinks-wheel-section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  position: relative;
}

.drinks-wheel{
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transition: rotate 0.8s;
}

.drink-picture{
  width: 7rem;
  height: 7rem;
  background-color: var(--bg);
}

.drinks-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 7rem;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.wrapper1{
  top: 37%;
  left: 0%;
}

.wrapper2{
  rotate: 90deg;
  top: 38%;
  left: 0%;
}

.name-and-change{
  width: 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.next,
.prev {
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="drinks-wheel-section">
  <div class="drinks-wheel">
    <div class="drinks-wrapper wrapper1">
      <div class="drink-picture" style="--bg:aqua;"></div>
      <div class="drink-picture" style="--bg:darkblue;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="drinks-wrapper wrapper2">
      <div class="drink-picture" style="--bg:black;"></div>
      <div class="drink-picture" style="--bg:brown;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="name-and-change">
    <button type="button" class="prev">&lt;</button>
    <p class="drink-name"></p>
    <button type="button" class="next">&gt;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

then in order to retrieve the rotation index (given you have 4 items in the wheel) you could use:

```js
const mod = (n, m) => ((n % m) + m) % m; // Fix negative Modulo

  // and inside the click function....
  const degAbs = mod(deg, 360);
  const index = degAbs / 360 * 4;
  console.log(index);      // 0, 1, 2, 3
```